# How ui-routes multiple view work in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In ui-router guide there is an example of page that has there main elements:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|               HEADER                      |
|------+------------------------------------|
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
| NAV  |        CONTENT                     |
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

and inside html they have:

```
<ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="nav"></ui-view>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

however there is very small example on state definition:

```
var mainState = {
  name: 'main',
  views: {
    header: 'headerComponent',
    nav: 'navComponent',
    content: 'mainComponent',
  }
}
```

Lets say that I would create three states:

```
var content1= {
  name: 'content1',
  url: '/content1',
  views: {
    header: 'headerComponent',
    nav: 'navComponent',
    content: 'content1Component',
  }
}
var content2= {
  name: 'content2',
  url: '/content2',
  views: {
    header: 'headerComponent',
    nav: 'navComponent',
    content: 'content2Component',
  }
}
var content3= {
  name: 'content3',
  url: '/content3',
  views: {
    header: 'headerComponent',
    nav: 'navComponent'
  }
}
```

Do I understand correctly:

1. that navigating from state `content1` to `content2`would change only the content part but header and nav would stay the same(with that I mean that ui-router understands that those to elements are not changing so it does not reload them)?
2. navigating to `content3` would leave content area empty?

Context of question. I am building small app with fullscreen google map always visible. Every page user navigates(about us, contact us etc) appears as modal window. But I have to ensure that main component(the map) always stays on DOM.